# My background image doesnt display right on my android phone

Tags: html, css

Ive been searching for an answer for this but could not find it. My website is using an background image in the html like this

```
html { background: url(img/bg.jpg) center top fixed no-repeat;
background-size:center 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

It works great in all the browsers ive checked except for the android webbrowser, nor the google chrome browser on the phone. Then It displays either 4 images or just one image at the top.

Anyone met this problem before and found a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876035/background-size-cover-not-working-in-portrait-on-android-tablet Check answer with 15 votes...

Comment: @nevermind Thank you man! It worked wonders (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `height: 100vh` to you body

Answer (score 0):

Guess this css can cover the screen.
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;