# Android chrome : Background with "background-size: cover;"

Tags: css, themes

I put a background on my homepage. It is correctly displayed on all browsers except on android chrome. Here is my css :

```
body.path-frontpage {
    background-image: url("/themes/contrib/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office/images/background.svg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my homepage :

https://www.s1biose.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem not too long ago. I fixed it by using the inline style in html. Apart from that I also found a thread where people post their approach to solve this I think you should check it out too!

[background-size: cover not working in portrait on Android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876035/background-size-cover-not-working-in-portrait-on-android-tablet)