# The background image of my website body is responsive on desktop but not on an actual phone

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have made a responsive website which is deployed on heroku. When I use chrome device toolbar to emulate phone viewport, the background image is scalable. But on an actual phone it's not; I just get a static zoomed-out image that occupies only part of the screen. Other than the image, everything else is working responsively.

Here's the CSS for my background image:

```
body {
  background-image: url('assets/backgroundimage2.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304494/responsive-web-design-is-working-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Comment: And when you say the background image is "responsive", what do you mean?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry, I meant that background image will resize/crop depending on window size, but that single image will still cover the full viewport.

Comment: @EternalHour I have the meta tag and the website is working as expected except for the image.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Scalable image is the correct term I think.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width: 100%` might be your solution to your problem.This tells your browser that the image shouldn't be larger than a mobile screen.

Comment: Doesn't it have the same effect as```background-size: cover;```?

Comment: Can you try using max-width maybe it will solve your problem. I'm not sure if there are same;

Comment: No dice. Weirdly enough, the background image is fine on mobile firefox. But chrome mobile is forcing the full image into view and thus, using only part of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here:
[background-size: cover not working in portrait on Android tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876035/background-size-cover-not-working-in-portrait-on-android-tablet)

For some reason, we have to specify height and minheight of html and body tags at 100%.